# why do nested control statements on one line fail in python?

Tags: python

I have been trying to convert a simple execution such as:

```
for x in xrange(10):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        print x, 'is even'
```

to a one liner version:

```
for x in xrange(10): if x % 2 == 0: print x, 'is even'
```

which gives me:

```
  File "foo.py", line 1
    for x in xrange(10): if x % 2 == 0: print x, 'is even'
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**I don't see any ambiguity in here. Is there a particular reason why this fails?**

Comment: Might I inquire why you're making it a one liner? It would seem to me that that will make it harder to read while not meaningfully changing the code.

Comment: @davemankoff I was just playing when I realized. I'm not sure if I will ever use it or not. It doesn't seem to me that ugly though..

Comment: Agree, it's not _that_ ugly, but I wouldn't say it helps the code either. And it's certainly a good thing to play with it and learn how a language works. I just want to warn you off doing one-liners for the sake of one-liners. As much as people like them, it's not a terribly great habit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [formal grammar for 2.7](http://docs.python.org/reference/grammar.html):

```
compound_stmt: if_stmt | while_stmt | for_stmt | try_stmt | with_stmt | funcdef | classdef | decorated

if_stmt: 'if' test ':' suite ('elif' test ':' suite)* ['else' ':' suite]
for_stmt: 'for' exprlist 'in' testlist ':' suite ['else' ':' suite]

suite: simple_stmt | NEWLINE INDENT stmt+ DEDENT

simple_stmt: small_stmt (';' small_stmt)* [';'] NEWLINE
small_stmt: (expr_stmt | print_stmt  | del_stmt | pass_stmt | flow_stmt |
             import_stmt | global_stmt | exec_stmt | assert_stmt)
```

If the `suite` had allowed a `compound_stmt` then what you suggest would be accepted.  But that would also allow something like this:

```
if True: try:
  # do something
except:
  # handle
foo()
```

Is that `except` outside the enclosing `if`?  Is the call to `foo` outside the enclosing `if`?  I think this shows that we really *don't* want in-lining compound statements to be allowed by the formal grammar.  Simply adding `suite: compound_stmt` makes the grammar ambiguous as I read it, where the same code can be interpreted with two or more different meanings, neither disprovable.

Basically, it's by design that what you ask is a parse error.  Reworking the formal grammar could allow the code in your example to work without other funny stuff, but it requires careful attention to ambiguity and other problems.

See also [Dangling Else](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else), a grammar problem that afflicted the standard Algol-60 language.  It's not always easy to find these kinds of problems, so a healthy fear of changing a working grammar is a good thing.

Comment: what do you mean by weird thing with `try`?

Comment: Edited answer with an example of `try` "weirdness".

Comment: Although I feel like I can still use it for many cases where there is no second statement, I guess the answer is in the lines of dangling else as you said..

Answer (score 5):

It's simply not allowed by [the grammar](http://docs.python.org/reference/grammar.html). The relevant productions are:

```
for_stmt: 'for' exprlist 'in' testlist ':' suite ['else' ':' suite]
suite: simple_stmt | NEWLINE INDENT stmt+ DEDENT
```

As you can see, after a `for` you can either put a simple statement or a "suite", i.e. an indented block. An `if` statement is a compound statement, not a simple one.

Two lines are the minimum to express this program:

```
for x in xrange(10):
    if x % 2 == 0: print x, 'is even'
```

(Of course, you can write equivalent programs that take only one line, such as

```
for x in xrange(0, 10, 2): print x, "is even"
```

or any of the other one-liners posted in response to this question.)

Comment: I still don't see a reason why this is implemented the way it is. Btw I wasn't just gonna print even numbers, that's just for demonstration..

Comment: @gokcehan I'm guessing so that python can retain it's indenting

Comment: @gokcehan: I understand that it was just an example. But jamylak is probably right, allowing an arbitrary number of control statements in a single line doesn't add to readability and defeats the purpose of the indentation-based syntax.

Comment: I guess I was more hoping for a technical answer, something like a counter example..

Answer (score 1):

try something like :

```
In [14]: from __future__ import print_function

In [17]: for x in xrange(10): print (x,'is even') if x%2==0 else None
   ....: 
0 is even
2 is even
4 is even
6 is even
8 is even
```

Comment: just a quick note, I have to leave a blank line for this to work, kind of interesting..

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
for y in (x for x in xrange(10) if x % 2 == 0): print y
```

Comment: I wish you hadn't used `x` for both loop variables.

Comment: Oh, thanks! For greater readability: `for y in (x for x in xrange(10) if x % 2 == 0): print y`

Comment: I don't really need to print even numbers with a one-liner. That's just an example..

Answer (score 1):

If you want something similar, use a list comprehension:

```
print '\n'.join('{0} is even'.format(x) for x in xrange(10) if x % 2 == 0)
```

Prints:

```
0 is even
2 is even
4 is even
6 is even
8 is even
```

Answer (score 1):

The Python docs about [compound statements](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html) states a ***reason*** for the *decision* on **why** does *the grammar disallow this*:

> A suite can be one or more semicolon-separated simple statements on
>   the same line as the header, following the header’s colon, or it can
>   be one or more indented statements on subsequent lines. Only the
>   latter form of suite can contain nested compound statements; the
>   following is illegal, **mostly because it wouldn’t be clear to which if
>   clause a following else clause would belong**:
>
> ```
> if test1: if test2: print x
> ```

So in [wberry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/729627/wberry)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12941217/611007) it was right about the [Dangling Else](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else).